# Making alphabetised nested lists inside a list

Tags: python

I have a task where i need to sort students into nested lists by their last names

```
new_group=[] # new, unnested group
for x in groups:
    for pupil in x:
        new_group.append(pupil)  #this adds every student to the unnested group

def sort(groups):
    new_group= sorted(new_group, key= lambda x: x.split(" ")[1])
```

I un-nested the group and sorted them alphabetically but now I have to put them back into nested lists
so if my list looks like: `new_group = ["James Allen", "Ricky Andrew", "Martin Brooks", "Andre Bryant"]`
I can turn it into: `[["James Allen", "Ricky Andrew"], ["Martin Brooks", "Andre Bryant"]]`

Comment: So, just to clarify, your question is how to nest the names into [[James Allen],[Ricky Andrew], [Martin Brooks], [Andre Bryant]] ?

Comment: What's the original grouping based on?

Comment: I am not sure I follow thewhole "nested" part. Please provide an example of `x`, `groups` and explain why you want to sort alphabetically ALL students, and not the single groups one by one. in the end, your result will be to have each group alphabetically sorted wrt the group content eg [Frank, Mary], [Albert, Carl, Karl] etc...

Comment: original group is :

Comment: oh its too long to post

Comment: I need to sort the people by their last names in 26 groups. Each group corresponding to a letter of the alphabet so the people whose last name start with A will be in group 1, people whose name starts with B will be in group 2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to produce your nesting:

```
from itertools import groupby

def last_name(name):
    return name.split()[-1] # Also works for middle names

def last_initial(name):
    return last_name(name)[0] # First letter of last name

groups = [['Martin Brooks'], ['Ricky Andrew'], ['Andre Bryant'], ['James Allen']]
sorted_pupils = sorted((pupil for g in groups for pupil in g), key=last_name)
grouped_pupils = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted_pupils, key=last_initial)]
print(grouped_pupils)
# Produces [['James Allen', 'Ricky Andrew'], ['Martin Brooks', 'Andre Bryant']]
```

Comment: @LucaMarinescu `grouped_pupils` can't possibly be one group, unless they all have the same last initial. It works fine with the test data you provided; maybe show the data you're actually using?

Comment: the problem is i need to put it inside the function that takes "groups" as an argument and the code return one group. If i delete the function it works so basically I have : ```def group_by_26(groups): ```  and then your code inside the function

Comment: I would post the list but it is 600 names long

Comment: and if i wante to sort them like that but after their first name ? how would i do the def first_name  ? i tried `def first_name(name):
        return name.split[1]`

Comment: @LucaMarinescu You need the first component of the split, so: `def first_name(name): return name.split()[0]` and then for the group key: `def first_initial(name): return first_name(name)[0]`